# I want to edit the same xampp database from different systems

Tags: xampp

I want to edit the same xampp database from different systems connected by LAN. I can view the db but can't edit it from the other systems.How do I do it?

Comment: You can contact the network admin.and take the permissions to open the other system in Lan.

Answer (score 0):

**you just need to put the IP of that PC where you install your MySQL server.** 
**For example:**

192.168.1.3/xampp/ OR 192.168.1.3/my_php_project/index.php

In the above link 192.168.1.3 is the IP of the PC where MySQL server is installed.